# How to add a value in a nested list that corresponding to another list?

Tags: python, list, iteration

I'm setting up a linear connection and I have two list:

```
a = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4]
b = [1,3,7,2,3,4,7,8,9]
```

`a[i]` related to `b[i]`

I regrouped `b` as `c`:

```
c = [[1, 3], [7], [2, 3], [4], [7, 8], [9]]
```

I tried to add the corresponding value of `a` in every sublist in `c` to get:

```
d = [[1, 1, 3], [1, 7], [2 ,2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 7, 8], [4, 9]]
```

The first value in every sublist of `c` that originally in `b` is related to `a` like `c[0][0] = b[0]`, and add `a[0]` to `c[0]`, `c[1][0] = b[2]`, so add `a[2]` to `c[1]`.

If sublist in `c` and the first value of the sublist = `b[i]`, add `a[i]` to every sublist.

I got stuck for this.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to do? what is the relation between A and B. Why d has only three `1`s but A and B have four altogether?

Comment: For every sublist in `c`, if `sublist[0]` = `b[i]`, add `a[i]` to `sublist`.

Is that Okay?

Answer (score 2):

You could build an iterator from `a` and take successive slices of it using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) in order to consume it according to the length of the sublists in `c`, but only select the first item from each slice:

```
from itertools import islice

a = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4]
c = [[1, 3], [7], [2, 3], [4], [7, 8], [9]]
a_ = iter(a)

[[list(islice(a_, len(j)))[0]] + [i for i in j] for j in c]
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 1, 3], [1, 7], [2, 2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 7, 8], [4, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method. Basic Way.

```
#!/bin/python

a = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4]

b = [1,3,7,2,3,4,7,8,9]

c = [[1, 3], [7], [2, 3], [4], [7, 8], [9]]

#d = [[1, 1, 3], [1, 7], [2 ,2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 7, 8], [4, 9]]

element_count=0
d=[]
for x in c:
    print (a[element_count])
    print(x)
    d.append([a[element_count]]+x)
    element_count+=len(x)
```